# Jquery issue with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/yTjUL/13/

The variable should be triggered on `click`, making the link change class from `on` to `off` and change colour from red to green. But instead it starts already green, thus making the function useless.

Why does it not work?

HTML

```
<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0)" class="on">CLICK HERE</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $myVar = $(document).find('.on').addClass('off').removeClass('on');
    $('link').click(function () {
        $myVar
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that the variable will store a chain of actions to perform later, when the variable is 'called,' but that's not (clearly) what happens: the first line, within the `ready()` handler, in the `var` assignment, finds the `.on` element and performs the actions you specify, storing the `.on` element(s) in the variable (as jQuery methods almost all return the `this` object).

Instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // use the `#link` notation, since 'link' is the id of the element:
    $('#link').click(function () {
        // assign a function to the click-event handler:
        $('.on').addClass('off').removeClass('on');
    });
});
```

Or, more simply (if you want to toggle between 'states') use `toggleClass()` and `$(this)` (rather than selecting from the whole of the document each time the user clicks the given element):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('on off');
    });
});
```

Also, rather than using `javascript:void(0)` in the `href`, simply use jQuery to prevent the default action, with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('on off');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yTjUL/21/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way, the variable will just contain the result of whatever methods you called, and for jQuery that means the element will be returned, so the variable `$myVar` only equals `$(document)` inside the event handler, it does not call the chained methods again.

You have to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').on('click', function () {
        $('.on').toggleClass('on off');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').click(function () {
        $(".on").addClass("off").removeClass("on");
    });
});
```

As Guilherme Sehn noted, the $myVar variable is not needed.  Just put your code in the click event.  In addition, the link selector needs to be "#link", not "link".

Answer (score 0):

By doing this, you'll be executing these actions and storing the return value (which will be the jQuery elements) inside `$myVar`. You can just put your code inside the click trigger function.

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    $('.on').addClass('off').removeClass('on');
});
```

Also, you forgot the `#` before your ID. Without that your code will select `link` tags, not the element with the id `link`. And you do not need to explicity use `$(document).find('.on')` as all DOM elements are inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant `$("#link")...` and not `$("link")`

And if I understand right - the full script should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
         $(".on").addClass("off").removeClass("off");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't invoke the function and your selector is wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#link').click(function () {
      $(document).find('.on').addClass('off').removeClass('on');
  });
});
```